# Performing random trials in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, rdd, flatten

I am learning pyspark recently and wanted to apply in one of the problems. Basically i want to perform random trials on each record in a dataframe.My dataframe is structured as below.

```
order_id,order_date,distribution,quantity
O1,D1,3 4 4 5 6 7 8 ... ,10
O2,D2,1 6 9 10 12 16 18 ..., 20
O3,D3,7 12 15 16 18 20 ... ,50
```

Here distribution column is 100 percentile points where each value is space separated.

I want to loop through each of these rows in the dataframe and randomly select a point in the distribution and add those many days to order_date and create a new column arrival_date.
At the end i want to get the avg(quantity) by arrival_date. So my final dataframe should look like

```
arrival_date,qty
A1,5
A2,10
```

What i have achieved till now is below

```
df = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("/tmp/test.csv")

def randSample(row):
    order_id = row.order_id
    quantity = int(row.quantity)
    data = []
    for i in range(1,20):
        n = random.randint(0,99)
        randnum = int(float(row.edd.split(" ")[n]))
        arrival_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row.order_date.split(" ")[0], "%Y-%m-%d") + datetime.timedelta(days=randnum)
        data.append((arrival_date, quantity))
    return data
        
finalRDD = df.rdd.map(randSample)
```

The calculations look correct, however the finalRDD is structured as list of lists as below

```
[
[(),(),(),()]
,[(),(),(),()]
,[(),(),(),()]
,[(),(),(),()]
]
```

Each of the list inside the main list is a single record . And each tuple inside the nested list is a trial of that record.
Basically i want the final output as flattened records, so that i can perform the average.

```
[
(),
(),
(),
]
```

Comment: Well, I was able to achieve this using a flatMap instead of map. That was a good learning for me. Performance looks good as well. Please provide any other easy(lesser lines of code) way.